# Strange Place to throw null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I tried to use the following code to check whether a field is null or not:

The rest of the code cycles through an ArrayList of objects while trying to see if a certain field is null in order to pick them out of the list. This fragment is meant to test if the object has a certain field as null.

```
if(obj.getfield() != null)
{
    //Take it out of the list
}
else
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

However, the line obj.getfield() != null threw a NullPointerException whenever it returned a null. Any luck guessing the cause of it?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: obj == null returns false.

Comment: I'm guessing `obj` is null.

Comment: But usually java would still allow me to compare a null to a null.

Comment: you are calling `getfield()` on `obj`.  Calling a method on null will cause a null pointer exception

Comment: You're not comparing null to null. You're calling `getField()` on a null variable, obj.

Comment: you have error whenever you call `obj.getfield()`, it is null, did you initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is obj is null.

You need to create the obj instance like so

```
    Object obj = new Object();
```

EDIT

Another possibility is that your are not declaring the field that getField() returns inside the constructor of whatever obj is an instance of. 
Ex

```
Class x
   int[] array;
   public x(){
      //does not contain 'array = new int[5];'
   }
```

Comment: However, I tried to test obj == null and got false.

Comment: @ZhehaoChen: you're not giving us nearly enough information for your question to be answerable.

Comment: Could you add the code where you create obj, the constructor of the class that obj is an instance of, and the getField method. Edit: the only other thing I can think of is that inside the constructor you never create the field that getField returns.

Answer (score 1):

The **only plausible explanation** for an NPE thrown this line:

```
    if (obj.getfield() != null)
```

is that `obj` is `null` at that point:

- check that `obj` has been initialized to a non-null
- check that `obj` is not being changed
- check that you haven't declared a local `obj` that shadows an instance variable with the same name ... or something like that
  value
- if the value of `obj` is coming from somewhere else, figure out why the value is `null`

Comparison of object references using `==` does not raise `NullPointerException`.

(Comparison of a primitive numeric type with a boxed type *can* raise an NPE ... if the boxed value is `null` ... but that's not going to happen here, assuming `obj` is a reference type.  But if you were nutty enough to declare `private int obj` ... )

---

If this does not answer your question, then please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that *demonstrates* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that  `obj` is `null`, therefore you can't call its method `getfield()`.

> *But usually java would still allow me to compare a null to a null.*

You are not comparing `null` with `null`, you are comparing

```
if (null.getfield() != null)
```

In fact, the alone expression

```
obj.getfield()
```

is throwing the exception, so it doesn't matter if you compare it with `null` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the exception by testing whether or not obj is null first, so the test on the obj field is not on a null Object.

```
    if(obj != null && obj.getfield() != null)
    {
        //Take it out of the list
    }
```

You don't seem to need the else clause if it does nothing. Hope that is useful.